# _netrc/.netrc alternative to cURL

Tags: git, http, authentication, curl, .netrc

I've been looking at Git and cURL and I found some references about .netrc, that may help on HTTP authentication. The problem is: .netrc is dumb, because it stores passwords in plain text format, which is a **big** security issue for the solution I'm developing.

Is there an alternative to the .netrc approach? Is it possible to develop an "authentication backend" to cURL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update [April 2013, git 1.8.3](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L119-L120):

> A **[new read-only credential helper](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc.perl)** (in `contrib/`) to interact with the `.netrc/.authinfo` files has been added.

That script would allow you to **use gpg-encrypted netrc files**, avoiding the issue of having your credentials stored in a plain text file.

> To enable this credential helper:

```
git config credential.helper '$shortname -f AUTHFILE1 -f AUTHFILE2'
```

> (Note that Git will prepend "`git-credential-`" to the helper name and look for it
> in the path.)

**See a full example at "[Is there a way to skip password typing when using `https:// github`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)"

---

Original answer (March 2011)

The only alternative (except not using it and going through ssh) would be to:

- encrypt that file (for instance, on Windows, with the utility '**[`crypt`](http://crypt.sourceforge.net/)**')
- decrypt it just before the curl call
- then encrypt it again right after the curl call

Note that on Unix, that file is normally in mode 600, only visible by you.
On Windows (`_netrc`), that file should be in your `HOMEDIR`, which shouldn't be accessible (through Windows ACL) to any other users.
But I still don't like a password in plain text...

[This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-396591.html), for example, goes through the same process (on Unix for gpg, but it still illustrates the solution nicely):

> Below I have included a sample script implementing the usage of '`gpg`', which can be used to encrypt the contents of a file. It's in shell script, however I'm sure you can adapt the concept to your perl script.

> I think for your needs the basic idea is:

> 1. create a plain-text file with your password (and other info)
>    2. encrypt it using `gpg` and store the encrypted file; dispose of the plain-text file
>    3. Within the perl script, decrypt the encrypted file into a plain-text file
>    4. read contents of plain-text file during runtime of your script
>    5. delete plain-text file as soon as possible.

> Here's just an example of the workings of gpg:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter your password: "
read pass

FILE=~/mypassword
echo $pass > $FILE
gpg -c $FILE
rm -f $FILE

gpg $FILE.gpg
MYPASSWORD=`cat $FILE`
rm -f $FILE

echo $MYPASSWORD
```

Comment: @Herberth: not directly, unless you replace the `curl` exe by a curl script (which then call the actual `curl` exe after decryption and before re-encryption)

Comment: Oh, I think it is not possible... git doesn't call curl with a system command, but with libcurl. Thanks for advance ;)