# File '_netrc' / '.netrc' is not accepted by Git

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, .netrc

I have set the %HOME% environment variable on my Windows installation.

In that folder I have put a file called _netrc. Inside that file I have:

```
machine code.google.com login <logon> password <censored>
```

But both, MSYS and Tortoise keep asking for a password.

I am using Windows 7, MSYSGit and TortoiseGit. Why does this not work?

I have found an article on Stack Overflow that said it must be named _netrc and not .netrc, but none of them work.

Comment: I have set the %HOME% already some time ago. So, yes there where multiple restarts. And yes, cmd echoes what is expected: http://h5.abload.de/img/echoy8j5.png

Comment: http://h4.abload.de/img/yesiamsure8pe1.png Yes, I am sure

Comment: Okay, I found the mistake. I had scorcher24@code.google.com in the url. That blocked git from using my .netrc.  Thanks eckes.

Comment: I've had the same issue, but with Cygwin git this solution did not work, FYI

Comment: You question answered my question... from it I knew that I should name the file only `_netrc`. Git Bash picked it right away! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you did everything that was described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows/6031266#6031266) and you set the right location for your `%HOME%` environment variable (confirm this with an `echo %HOME%` and check that in that location there's a `_netrc` file), there must something be wrong in the usage of your repository.

The URL to clone a Google Code repository is `https://user.googlecode.com/svn/trunk` (see [this Google link](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ImportingFromGit) for that).

So, you have to do a

```
git svn clone https://user.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

in order to import your Google repository.

Answer (score 2):

I've been bashing my brains against this one too and I have a solution different from those posted.

Ensure that your _netrc file is Ascii encoded. If using ECHO redirecting to a file on standard out, Windows uses the UCS-2 LE BOM file format. Some other apps might also have a different default from Ascii.

So, if creating this file via script, use `Set-Content -Encoding Ascii` rather than a STOUT redirect. If creating this file via notepad++ or vim, ensure the encoding is set to ASCII.

Comment: this one saved me my work, I had a script to generate _netrc content, and works fine on a machine, then when tried on a different machine, nothing works, I did everything. until I found your comment, and then finally all hope restored. BTW it wasnt that clear how to use the command to be honest.