# Force Git to prompt for username and password

Tags: git, authentication, push, google-code

I closed a PHP project that I posted on google code.

The problem is that when I try to use the following command:

```
git push origin master
```

I get the following authentication error message:

```
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your generated googlecode.com password; see https://code.google.com/hosting/settings
```

How can I force Git to prompt for username and password in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm confused. You are trying to work with a Git repo on google code that you already closed?

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9186888/550309).

Go to the URL in error message you got to get your password, and then follow the instructions.

> For Git repositories, you can add the following line to your .netrc file recording your password for each repository domain you have commit access to. Make sure you have set the permissions on .netrc so that only your user account can read it.

```
machine code.google.com login user@gmail.com password qwertyasdfg
```

I'll also quote a comment under that answer that may be helpful:

> removing the username from the .git/config forced git to reask for username and password