# Push to code.google.com in windows using git

Tags: windows, git

Related questions:
[netrc not accepted by git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903158/netrc-not-accepted-by-git) and [Git - How to use .netrc file on windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password)

I am trying to push changes to a code.google.com git repository. I am using Git Extensions. My HOME variable is set in both Windows and Git Bash.

```
C:\> echo %HOME%
C:\Users\Username

$ echo $HOME
/c/Users/Username
```

And I have added a file in %HOME% called _netrc

```
machine code.google.com
login username@gmail.com
password GOOGLEGENERATED
```

Obviously Username is replaced by my username and GOOGLEGENERATED is the google generated password. When attempting to push, I get this error message:

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe push -u --recurse-submodules=check
>   "origin" master:master Done fatal: remote error: Invalid
>   username/password. You may need to use your generated googlecode.com
>   password; see https://code.google.com/hosting/settings

The related questions suggest that everything is setup properly, but it is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: is the username already specified in origin?

Comment: In Settings - Global settings tab? User name = Username@gmail.com and user email = Username@gmail.com. Or is there somewhere else I need to set it at?

Comment: check in `.git/config`, what is the value of url under [remote "origin"]?

Comment: url = https://Username@code.google.com/p/project

Comment: That was supposed to read: url - "https: //Username@code.google.com/p/project" (Space added to prevent automatic hyperlink

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove username@ from the url entry for origin in `.git/config`

Comment: Might also be helpful to some to point out that this is done in the repository folder, not the global config. (was the case for me anyway)

Answer (score 7):

So, for those who are new at this, do the following in git bash:

---

git config --global user.name "google.username"

git config --global user.email "google.username@gmail.com"

git remote set-url origin https://code.google.com/p/projectname

---

This worked for me.  I didn't do anything with a _netrc or .netrc file.

Comment: Worked like a charm and I think