# Git submodule URL not including username?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository set up with several submodules, which creates a `.gitmodules` file that is a tracked file in the parent repository. However, there are other developers wanting to work on this repository, and check out the submodules. But currently the URLs for the remote submodule repositories contain my username; in the `.gitmodules` file it's something like:

```
[submodule foo]
  path = sub/foo
  url = https://myuser@example.com/git/foo.git
```

Obviously other developers can't fetch from `example.com` as `myuser` (they don't have my password); how can I have one main repository that multiple developers can pull/push to, and allow them to have individual access to the submodules (setting up a single username they all share on the submodule host server would work, but is not good user management)?

Comment: Do you own that server? Have you looked at gitolite? Can you just use public hosting?

Comment: @Jefromi Bitbucket hosting currently, though gitolite looks like it would work for self-hosting.

Comment: See this: http://blog.tremily.us/posts/Relative_submodules/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're using HTTP basic authentication over HTTPS to allow only particular developers to access the repository.  In that case, you can commit a `.gitmodules` that looks like:

```
[submodule foo]
  path = sub/foo
  url = https://example.com/git/foo.git
```

... i.e. without a user name, and then tell each developer to put their username and password in their `~/.netrc` file.  (If you're using Windows, then there is [some good advice on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows).)  A simple `.netrc` file might look like:

```
machine example.com
  login myusername
  password areamandyingtotellsomeonehiscoolpassword
```

---

*Update: An alternative, which doesn't involve using `.netrc`, would be the following:*

Again, remove the user name from the URL in `.gitmodules` and commit and push that change.  When someone clones the repository they would first run:

```
git submodule init
```

... which will set the config option `submodule.sub/foo.url` to the URL in `.gitmodules`.  However, the `init` step won't clone the submodule into place until you do `git submodule update`, so you can do:

```
git config submodule.sub/foo.url https://myuser:mypass@example.com/git/foo.git
```

... and then:

```
git submodule update
```

To clone the submodules with the right user name.  Note that then your username and password for HTTP authentication will be stored in your git config.

Comment: That's good for system-wide configuration; in the edge case where you have a different username for git repo access than you do for other access, it's not idea. I found that removing the username from the repo URLs prompts for both username and password, so that works, if not ideal. If only git allowed something like a `remote.origin.user` config option...

Comment: Do you really use `.netrc` for other authentication?

Comment: I don't, but I don't know if others would; to me the ideal solution would be one completely within git and its configuration, without having to modify other parts of the OS, in case a user was using that file for another purpose that conflicted.

Comment: @MidnightLightning: I've added an alternative to my answer.  Using SSH is generally more flexible than using HTTPS, in case that's an option.

Comment: @MidnightLightning "I found that removing the username from the repo URLs prompts for both username and password, so that works, if not ideal." Can you provide an example of this, that sounds ideal to me. Or did you find another better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Can someone explain this syntax: 'submodule.sub/foo.url'? In his example .gitmodules excerpt, 'foo' is a subsection of 'submodule'. Why doesn't the text I'm asking about read: 'submodule.foo.url'?

Comment: @BobbyA - when you use `git config` to set some config, that's modifying `.git/config`. That's a separate config file with different sections and meaning from `.gitmodules`. In `.git/config` for this example there would be a section: `[submodule "sub/foo"]`, containing `url = https://myuser:mypass@example.com/git/foo.git`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 34):

Actually you can specify a "relative" path to a submodule in `.gitconfig`:

```
[submodule foo]  
path = sub/foo  
url = ./git/foo.git
```

This url will reference same host (https://example.com) as the repository itself.

Comment: It's not taking the same host it's taking the same URL e.g: ssh://user@example.com:29412/mainmodule/submodule

Comment: If master-project url is https://user@host.org/team/project.git and submodule url is https://user@host.org/team/submodule.git, you can set .gitmodule submodule url to `../../team/submodule.git` it worked for me. You could probably make the path shorter like this `../submodule.git`. `git submodule sync` and `git config -e` might help you.

Answer (score 30):

This threaded helped me, but I would add that after you modify the content of the file *.gitmodules* you need to execute the following command so git will pick it up:

```
git submodule sync
```

Comment: This is what fixed the issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: This also corrected the issue for me.

Comment: I could not figure why my submodules was still asking for HTTP credentials after changing it to SSH, maybe something in the .git cache. Anyway, **THIS** worked !

Answer (score 17):

Antonk's answer won't work for teams because an individual's .gitconfig or .git/config is not under version control.

However it did lead me to experimenting with the url in .gitmodules.

```
[submodule foo]
path = sub/foo
url = ../foo.git
```

worked for me, assuming that the submodule repo is in the same url as the parent.

Comment: Works awesomely great! No hosts, ports or usernames anywhere except on the supermodule clone command line.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ssh authentication.

just replace this

```
[submodule foo]
  path = sub/foo
  url = https://myuser@example.com/git/foo.git
```

with this

```
[submodule foo]
  path = sub/foo
  url = git@example.com:git/foo.git
```

Comment: You're still specifying a user; now instead of assuming other maintainers have the password to the `myuser` account, you're assuming they have the password to the `git` user account, no?

Comment: Nope. There are Git servers that just look up your public key to match your user. Among those servers, there is Github, Atlassian Bitbucket Server (formerly Stash) and Atlassian Bitbucket (the SaaS version). This is neat because you don't have such issues with the username in the url

Answer (score 6):

You can try `.insteadOf`, e.g.

```
git config --global url."ssh://YOUR_USERNAME@gerrit.foobar.com:29418/".insteadOf "ssh://gerrit.foobar.com:29418/"
```

Each developer will have to do this once on each computer they work on.

Comment: The great thing about this is you do it once and then everything just works, including "git clone --recurse-submodules". It does require the "YOUR_USERNAME" string to be consistent, though.

Comment: If you do cloning on CI you can use env as well: `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS="'url.https://${SECRET_TOKEN}@github.com.insteadof=ssh://git@github.com'"`. Note additional quoting: `'`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in combination with **Gerrit** (via ssh).
Removing the username worked,
 so my **.gitmodules** looks like this now:

```
[submodule "sub/module1"]
    path = sub/module1
    url = ssh://servername:29418/module1
```

Comment: Is this suppose to work like that ? It works on windows but not on linux

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if it is supposed to, but it works for me on Windows and Linux. It possibly depends on what the ssh stuff is doing in the background - as you don't give the user, it will have to use a default user.

Comment: I found out more about that : Actually, your session username have to be the same as your ssh username for it to work. Or to get around this, you have to configure .ssh/config to use a specific username for each ssh server

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `.gitmodules` and remove the username from the `url`:

```
[submodule foo]
  path = sub/foo
  url = https://example.com/git/foo.git
```

And finally:

```
cd foo/
git submodule init
git submodule update

# Will be prompted to provide username and password
```

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively you can use **HTTPS** in place of **SSH** which will prompt you for your username and password:

[image]