# Clone a repo with submodules: override credentials

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-clone, git-config

I have to *automate* the cloning of a repository and fetching all its submodules. The URLs for the repository submodules are specified at `.gitmodules`. If I were to go with defaults I would just do

```
git clone --recursive https://username:password@url.git
```

The problem is credentials aren't included in `.gitmodules` file and I am prompted for those when I clone. I have to use HTTPS rather than SSH.

I tried to submit the credentials using git config:

```
git clone https://username:password@url.git my_repo
cd my_repo
git submodule init
git config submodule.my_submodule.url "https://username:password@url/my_submodule.git"
git submodule update
```

but I get prompted for credentials in the last update step. I've checked that the submodule URL is correct and has proper credentials in `.git/config` file.

Comment: did you try ``git submodule sync`` ?

Comment: Turns out I wasn't using proper name for `my_submole`. Got misled by tab completion. I found proper name in `.gitmodules`.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you are trying to use git credentials but not having any luck.

**Option 1**

Add credentials using the credential helper:

```
git config credential.https://example.com.username myusername
git config credential.helper "$helper $options"
```

Check your *~/.gitconfig* and verify that the appropriate entry is added.

Further reading:
http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

**Option 2**

I would double check the contents of your .git-credentials file and make a new entry for the submodule if it is not present. This file is used internally by the git credentials helper.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

**Option 3**

Easy solution in windows is to remove the username, password from modules file:

```
[submodule foo]
  path = sub/foo
  url = https://example.com/git/foo.git
```

And create a ~/.netrc file.

```
machine example.com
  login myusername
  password areamandyingtotellsomeonehiscoolpassword
```

Kudos to [Git submodule URL not including username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714326/git-submodule-url-not-including-username).

Comment: Note that when you use setup a creadential helper you might need to provide a path to a file explicitly. Git assumes $HOME variable is set and that is not true e.g. in Jenkins.

Comment: So a basic usage would be:
`git config --global credential.helper store` 

But you might need to use:
`git config --system credential.helper 'store --file /root/.git-credentials'`

Answer (score 8):

After editting the `.gitmodules` file you need to apply changes using

```
git submodule sync
```

The next time you run `git submodule update` the new url will be used.

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you are running CI and have access to a private token and already know the path to the submodule, you could use

```
git config credential.helper store
echo "https://LOGIN:${PAT}@github.com/path/to/submodule.git" > ~/.git-credentials
```

The next submodule update will not ask for credential.

Obviously, you'll want to clean this up once your done. In my case, I run in a docker container, so I don't have this concern.