# Trying to "install" github, .ssh dir not there

Tags: windows, github, ssh

I'm following the step by step directions of github.
I'm trying to install it on windows 7.

The documentation states the key will be stored in
`/users/tedpottel/.ssh/`. I turned on hidden files, and still can't see the folder.
Then I tried to create a new folder with the same file name, `.ssh`,
I got a `invalid file name` error. Windows will not let me create a file name begining with a period.

I'm a little confused, wouldn't `.ssh` be a invalid file name?
I'm stuck, any help would be GREAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create your ssh directory in a DOS session:

```
cd c:\Users\tedpottel
mkdir .ssh
```

Use the [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) provided by [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) to launch your DOS session.
Path like `/users/tedpottel/.ssh/` are unix-like paths that you can use in a bash session, also included in `msysgit`.

In that `git-cmd.bat`, the environment variable `HOME` will be set to `c:\Users\tedpottel`, which is important if you want ssh to works properly (it will look for public/private keys in `%HOME%\.ssh`).