# code.google.com: git: fatal: remote error: Repository not found

Tags: git, google-code

I have created a new repository in `code.google.com`, generated the `code.google.com` password and updated my `~/.netrc` with

```
machine code.google.com login <email-id> password <password>
```

As per the instruction in the `code.google.com`, I was able to `clone` the repository using the following command:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/<repository-name>/
```

and after that I added some files to the repository and executed, `git add`, followed by `git commit`. But when I executed `git push origin master` it gave the following error

```
fatal: remote error: Repository not found
```

When google'ed for this issue, I found couple of links but the work-around that was mentioned in that didn't seem to work. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

UPDATE: 
I have tried the following work-arounds but unsuccessful:

1. Update the `url` in the `.git/config` to take `username` and `password`
2. Give the `username` and `password` in the `url` in the `git clone` command
3. Update `username` and `password` with global `git` config command

Comment: Just to be sure, your `.netrc` has three lines in it, right? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password/6031266#6031266) Not one line like shown ni your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'git remote show origin' to confirm the remote communication.

Is the 'security' button checked at [Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/hosting/settings).  If so, maybe you are using the wrong password (Google Code password versus Google Account password).

[edit]

When you clone a Google project, you get a custom repository name.  For example, I cloned the 'playn' project and was given a project name of 'gozoner-playn-too' (based on the info that I provided).  When you make your local clone it needs to be of this repository.  In my case:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/gozoner-playn-too
```

And the push then works:

```
$ git push origin
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 256 bytes, done.
...
```

Note, if you've already checked out the wrong clone (like I suspect) you can change the url to the correct one with:

```
git remote set-url origin https://code.google.com/p/gozoner-playn-too
```

After this the .git/config file has this:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = https://code.google.com/p/gozoner-playn-too
```

Comment: `* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://code.google.com/p/<repo>
  Push  URL: https://code.google.com/p/<repo>
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)`

Comment: The security button is not checked.. And I use exactly (copy-paste) the same credentials that is shown in hosting project page in my ~/.netrc file. I have all the admin authority. I see all the permission buttons checked.

Comment: Yes.  I am able to recreate your exact problem with my Google Code account.  The 'git remote show' looks perfect; 'git fetch' seems to work; 'git push' fails.

Comment: Ack. A quick google search tells that there are many users who face this problem. I'll keep searching for a solution. Will let you know if I come across one!

Comment: The permission on your ~/.netrc is 600?  The 'machine' line in that file ends with a newline?

Comment: Yes and yes. They seem to be fine.

Comment: Perhaps it is the trailing slash ('/') in your git clone command.  Is that slash shown in the URL when you do 'git remote show origin'?  If so, the code.google.com web server might not be seeing a valid https URL.

Answer (score 1):

You did everything as the code.google.com says.But you also need to add the remote origin to git.It is like...

```
git remote add origin https://code.google.com/p/your-project-name
```

then push the added code like...

```
git push orgin --all
```

For start-up to code.google.com git use see the complete instruction here http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2012/06/1.html

Hope it helps!