# Automate username/password entry when git pushing over http from windows machine

Tags: windows, git

I am pushing from my windows box to a repository cloned from an http (not ssh) address.  Each push, I have to enter my u/p.  I want to automate this process.  I have tried the following:

```
$ git config credential.helper cache
$ git config credential.helper 'cache timeout=360000'
```

But those settings had no effect and I still have to enter the u/p each time.  Is there any way to automate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use _netrc file to store your username/password for remote machine, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266/1155892)

Comment: On my work machine the _netrc method would not work when placed into my profile C:\Users\Name.Domain. Moved to C:\Users\Name and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Git support a more streamlined [credentials API](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/technical/api-credentials.html).  Depending on implementation of the credentials helper, this is typically more convenient and secure than using .netrc.

A popular windows credentials helper is [git-credential-winstore.exe](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/87586). Simply download to the git/bin path and execute.  Github supplies a [similar helper](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-windows).

Additional detail here (but not specific to Windows):

- [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Answer (score 0):

Note: the syntax would be:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

Otherwise, the default cache time is 15 minutes.

Actually, Git 2.39 (Q4 2022) updates the credential-cache documentation to provide a more realistic example.

See [commit f13c3f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f13c3f28e7e8959fa23958323458b7e4437f2dda) (09 Nov 2022) by [M Hickford (`hickford`)](https://github.com/hickford).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit 3f98d7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f98d7ab1b816f403fc12c7a7e056ceba230bab9), 18 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f13c3f28e7e8959fa23958323458b7e4437f2dda): increase example cache timeout to 1 hour
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: M Hickford</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Previously, the example *decreased* the cache timeout compared to the default, making it less user friendly.
>
> Instead, nudge users to make cache more usable.
> Many users choose store over cache.
> See [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAGJzqskRYN49SeS8kSEN5-vbB_Jt1QvAV9QhS6zNuKh0u8wxPQ@mail.gmail.com/)
>
> The default timeout remains 15 minutes.
> A stronger nudge would be to increase that.

`git credential-cache` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f13c3f28e7e8959fa23958323458b7e4437f2dda/Documentation/git-credential-cache.txt#L72):

> variable (this example increases the cache time to 1 hour):
>
> ```
>  $ git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
> ```