# TortoiseGit - When does it ask for a username and password?

Tags: asp.net, git, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, tortoisegit

I want to implement a little Git Webserver running as an IIS application. I managed it that I can pull and push from and to it. But now I want to implement some basic credentials.

What I do not want to have is, to add a remote url like http://username:password@domain.tld/repo.git. I do not want to have the password in the url (username will be ok).

Currently I want to have this for the HTTP protocol (HTTPS will also be fine)

What do I have to return from my server to tortoisegit, so it will prompt me for a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) would use the same curl commands than msysgit to access to an http server (IIS or other).

See "[Git - How to use .netrc file on windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password)": you can save your username and password in `%HOME%/_netrc` (you need to define `HOME` on Windows).

The other option is to use the [credential helpers packages with git1.7.9+](https://github.com/blog/1104-credential-caching-for-wrist-friendly-git-usage). You enter your username and password *once* per session (and avoid the `_netrc` plain text file).