# On OS X how do I securely save passwords for git repos accessed via https?

Tags: macos, git, passwords, password-encryption, git-clone

I access a lot of git repos on my Mac, that are cloned via https:

```
git clone https://git.someserver.com/myrepo1.git
```

which prompts me for username and password.  I'm tired of entering these passwords each time I want to fetch/pull/push, and would like a secure mechanism for remembering them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell git to use a credential helper to remember your passwords, and rather than use a text file, you can tell it to use the keychain:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

That will be a global setting, so now once you connect to a repo and enter your username/password the first time, it's remembered on subsequent actions.

(this specific answer gleaned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github/18362082#18362082))