# Purpose of the '.netrc' file

Tags: git, .netrc

When I try to use Google Cloud's *Push-to-Deploy* feature, they asked me to add some credential in the `.netrc` file. What is the `.netrc` file? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a file that is often used by Unix programs to hold access details for remote sites. It was originally created for use with FTP.

See [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266) for its use with Git on Windows specifically.