# Git push and pull without entering password for the remote server

Tags: git, remote-server

I have set up git shell

When I push the change to the remote server which is user@192.168.0.24 it asks for a password of that user.

I want to avoid entering the password every time I do git push origin master or git pull.

I have generated a key on putty for the user@192.168.0.24

How can I do store the password or use ssh keys?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 cases:

1. Remove passphrase from your key (by default - `id_rsa`). If you use
   putty - do this using `puttygen`. If u use pure msysgit do the
   command:

   ```
   $ ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
   ```
2. Use `pageant` from putty package to store your passphrase. It would ask passphrase only once for Windows user login session.

Comment: So when I log in through git to pull changes it won't ask me for password

Answer (score 0):

You want to tell the server about the preshared key (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) or put the user's password in .netrc ([Git - How to use .netrc file on windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password)).

Answer (score 0):

First ensure, you can ssh to the server without a password:

`ssh 192.168.0.24`

If this asks you for a password, you need to add your public key to the server in .ssh/authorized_keys Then ensure you can ssh again without a password.

Then use ssh protocol to clone/pull/push your git repo: `git clone user@192.168.0.24:repo.git`