# Auto input username and password git

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

Working on a bash script which will pull from my repo and which will autowrite the username and password to the input prompt.

This didn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

git pull -u origin master

echo "username"
echo "password"
```

When I run the script it ask for the username and password and doesn't autofill it.

Comment: Why not set up key authentication instead?

Comment: I am trying to do it with HTTPS.

Comment: Why not using a git credential helper instead? (links in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26944404/6309). It is made for https.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git