# Kendo UI with bower and TeamCity (CI)

Tags: kendo-ui, credentials, bower-install

I've got an existing project running that I have added kendo ui to via bower. We have a licensed copy so I am using the professional package.

Our TeamCity server is running Windows with many build agents, how can I pass the credentials to bower to authenticate with the kendo ui repo ?

I would prefer not to run a command on each build agent machine, and don't mind if I have to store the credentials in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [.netrc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/bower#storing-repository-credentials) file should work. [Make sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password) it is stored in the right directory for Windows. Usually it should be the home directory of the user that your TeamCity server runs as.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The problem I had was the file being called .netrc instead of _netrc and not it being in the root of the project rather than the current users folder.