# Git .netrc file authentication issue

Tags: git, github, .netrc

I am using GitHub. I created a repository and cloned it on my Ubuntu machine.
I have made an entry in the `.netrc` file as follows:

```
machine https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git
login xxx
xxx
```

I am expecting that Git will not ask me for the username and password after this entry in the `.netrc` file. But Git prompts for credentials even after this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you expect such things from git?

Comment: git by default prompts for username and password every time your make push or pull request. To avoid this you can make an entry in .netrc file. [Link](https://gist.github.com/technoweenie/1072829)

Comment: AFAIK the `machine` should just be the host name, without any protocol or path. So in your case just `github.com`. There is no more fine-grained login definition than on the host name possible with `.netrc`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `~/.netrc` (or `%HOME%\_netrc` on Windows) file isn't enough.

It is best to use that file ***encrypted***, with `gpg` + `netrc` alone, as [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309).

Or to use a script managing the encryption.
You would need, in that second case, to:

- copy the [`git-credential-netrc.perl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e67fbf927dfdf13d0b21dc6ea15dc3c7ef448ea0/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc.perl) file anywhere in your `$PATH`/`%PATH%`,
- add:

  ```
    cd yourRepo
    git config credential.helper "netrc -d -v"
  ```

(You can remove `-d` and `-v` once it is working: those are debug flags)

- use your login in the remote URL:

  ```
    git set-url origin https://yourLogin@github.com/yourLogin/yourRepo
  ```

See "[Git - How to use .netrc file on Windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266/6309)" for the general principle of a credential "netrc" helper (Git 1.8.3+).

Comment: I think this is a good solution, but I have some security concerns. You are putting a username and password in a file on your computer which is readable from mostly everybody. Better choice here would be to use a SSH-Key and to put the SSH-Key in the SSH-Agend.

Comment: @ckruczek I know, and I agree with you! I only use *gpg2 encrypted* _netrc file myself: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309. Same credential helper, but with gpg encryption.

Comment: Looks like `git-credential-netrc.perl` itself logs the password in plain text to the console... so there's no use in encrypting `.netrc` / `_netrc`, I guess.

Comment: @sschuberth Interesting! I have looked ar https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc.perl, and did not see a log(password) in there. But these days (2021, 6 years later), I would use GCM-core anyway, rather than netrc, encrypted or not: https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager (recently renamed GCM: https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/pull/542)

Comment: Looks like the user and password are logged because I used `-v` in `git config credential.helper "netrc -d -v"`. I should have omitted that.

Comment: @sschuberth OK, that makes more sense now. `netrc` with a verbose option is kind of dangerous indeed.

Comment: BTW, I was pretty sure that at some point in time (and also via the SO link you provide) Git was able to use an *unencrypted* `.netrc` file out of the box, without the need to install `git-credential-netrc.perl`. Am I really mistaken here?

Comment: So, Git uses `git-remote-https` in case of HTTPS,. which in turn is implemented via *libcurl*, which in turn [is configured with `CURL_NETRC_OPTIONAL`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d530dc0024503ab4218fe6c4395b8a0aa245478/http.c#L788), so I'd expect (unencrypted) `.netrc` support to work out of the box.

Comment: @sschuberth Sure. You can see me using `netrc` out of the box in a `credential.helper` back in 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I was confused as your answer says that just having a `.netrc` file isn't enough.

Comment: @sschuberth OK. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 2):

as @sschuberth mentioned removing the protocol http:// or https:// worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when it was asking for a username and password constantly after my token expired, so what I had to do was ***write new .netrc file from scratch with the new token***
and overwrite the old one. after that, it worked just fine and this was on ***Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS***