# is there any other way to push the built project to GitHub in Jenkins pipeline rather than using SSH agent?

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-agent

I'm using Jenkins pipelines to do project automation. I'm successfully able to build and publish the app but when I try to push the built project into GitHub repository using ssh-agent I get an error as below

> [Pipeline] { (push to git)
>       [Pipeline] sshagent
>       [ssh-agent] Using credentials OABLN709$
>       [ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
>       Could not find ssh-agent: IOException: Cannot run program "ssh-agent": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file
>   specified
>       Check if ssh-agent is installed and in PATH
>       [ssh-agent] FATAL: Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
>       [ssh-agent] Diagnostic report
>       [Pipeline] // sshagent
>       [Pipeline] }
>       [Pipeline] // stage
>       [Pipeline] }
>       [Pipeline] // withEnv
>       [Pipeline] }
>       [Pipeline] // node
>       [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: [ssh-agent] Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider.
>           at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentStepExecution.initRemoteAgent(SSHAgentStepExecution.java:175)
>           at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentStepExecution.start(SSHAgentStepExecution.java:63)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:270)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:180)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2538.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>           at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
>           at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
>           at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
>           at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
>           at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
>           at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:59)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:133)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:660)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:402)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:400)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:659)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:279)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:547)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:546)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:269)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:446)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:445)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:268)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:484)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:483)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:267)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:299)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:585)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:584)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:296)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:363)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:362)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:265)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:612)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:611)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:250)
>           at ***cps.transform***(Native Method)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1072.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
>           at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
>           at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
>           at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>           at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Finished: FAILURE

Jenkins script for pipeline is code script I used for jenkins pipeline is

```
stage('gitpush') {
steps{
sshagent (credentials: ['mygithubcredentialsID']) {
        sh("git clone https://github.com/mygithub/repository.git")
    }

    sshagent (credentials: ['mygithubcredentialsID']) {

        sh("(git add ranger-policies/policies.json)")
        sh("(git commit -m 'daily backup of ranger-policies/policies.json')")
        sh('(git push git@github.com:mygithub/repository.git)')
    }

}
}
}
```

I tried all possible way to fix this issue but they all didn't work out in my windows 10 PC. So I'm trying other way to push the built project into GITHUB repository apart from using SSH agent plugin . is there any other way to do this task? Thanks

Comment: You can use http and authenticate using a token

Comment: hey thanks, can u share me some examples based on this method that'll be very helpful to me. @StephenKing

Comment: you can use .netrc which is very easy but not that secure. Check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609203/git-netrc-file-authentication-issue