# Cannot push to Git after using new username

Tags: git, push

I was using another `user.name` and `user.email`, and I changed my `user.name` and `user.email` for this current repo. Now, I cannot push to the repo. I am etting the following message:

```
$ git push
remote: Permission to rrick3456/JS-Koans.git denied to rperro.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rrick3456/JS-Koans.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
$
```

I did a `git config --list` to make sure the username and email were correct.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745213/changed-github-password-no-longer-able-to-push-back-to-the-remote

Comment: I had a similar problem, after cloning a fork. I got the same error. It turned out I forgot to give my self push access , aka forgot to add myself as a contributor. So, is your old username listed as a contributor in this repo?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to check your repo I got 404.

Are you sure your link is correct? After that I tried to find your git account and I couldn't find a user with username 'rrick3456'. I think you have messed up something.

If you wish give us link to your profile in git so we can help you clone/fork to the repo you want.

Comment: The user doesn't exist either