# Changed credentials on Github and now I can't pull from a remote repository

Tags: git, authentication, github

I changed my password on Github. After doing that I am able to run local commands but I can't pull or push to a remote repository. I get the error `remote: Repository not found.` I tried removing and re-adding the remote branch but that did not work. When I run `ssh -T git@github.com`, it tells me that I am, in fact, authenticated. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you happen to also change your username? that would affect your repo URL.

Comment: No, I did not. Just the password.

Comment: Does `git remote -v` return the correct URL?

Comment: Yes, it does return the correct URL

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by including my username in the repository url.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use HTTP Basic Authentication instead of ssh to push to GitHub, which it looks like you *don't*, the steps to troubleshoot:

> 1. Confirm the accuracy of the remote push HTTPS URL syntax via `git remote get-url --push <name>`
> 2. Confirm GitHub access permissions via API endpoint `GET /repos/:owner/:repo`
> 3. Remove any cached credentials in OSX Keychain or _netrc credential helper as per [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/)'s answer to ["Changed GitHub password, no
>      longer able to push back to the remote"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745213/):

You can also bypass credentials caching altogether by embedding credentials information inside your push URL:

```
git remote \
set-url ${remoteName} \
https://${username}:${password}@github.com/${username}/$[repoName}.git
```